# Solo muestra la primera palabra de cadena (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

me gustaría que este return me devuelva toda la cadena que contiene la variable data.notas. Ahora mismo solo me devuelve la primera palabra. En cuanto llega al primer espacio en blanco corta. Estoy usando tooltip de Bootsrap 3 sobre datatables. Lo que hago es que  en una columna de la tabla se muestre el contenido de la columna con un tooltip que en este caso es de boostrap.

Ejemplo: `data.notas="hola como estas";`

resultado: hola

```
"columns": [  
  {"data": null,
   "render": function (data, type, full, meta) 
     {
       return "<span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title= Notas:" +
           data.notas + ">" + data.name + "</span>";
     }
  }, 
  {"data": "colab_name"}
]
```

Comment: Con el código que has puesto es difícil imaginarse el por qué te puede estar pasando ese error. Si pudieses subir un ejemplo de código funcional en el que te ocurra eso que nos comentas sería más sencillo el ayudarte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te faltan las comillas para el atributo `title`, si ellas sólo la primera palabra que pongas se toma en cuenta, el resto se asume que son otros atributos:

```html
<span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title= Notas: nota a mostrar> Ejemplo sin comillas</span>

<span data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Notas: nota a mostrar'> Ejemplo con comillas</span>
```

Para evitar estos errores te recomiendo el uso de *string templates*:

```js
let data= { notas: 'Esto es una nota', name: 'Juan Pablo'};

let generadorSpan = function (data) {
  return (`<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" 
  title="Notas: ${data.notas}">${data.name}</span>`);
}

console.log(generadorSpan(data));
```